# Using log scale on vertical axis with values less than 1

Tags: google-sheets, charts, google-visualization

I have some data in a Google spreadsheet that need to be plotted. It needs to be plotted in log scale, however, all of it is less than 1. When I select "Log scale" on the vertical axis, all the columns start at 1 and go downwards, like this:

[image]

This doesn't look very good, since I want to compare the three values and show that "test3" is much higher than the other two, but the column for "test3" is smaller, so visually it seems that "test3" is the smallest value (at first glance, anyway). Is it possible to have them the opposite way, that is, start at the bottom of the chart (at whatever minimum value is set for the vertical axis), and go up to the given value?

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, at present this isn't possible to do.*

#### More Information

I did a bit of digging for this and I found that there's a workaround described on [Web Apps Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/119600), but I couldn't get this to work for log graphs - the workaround assumes that the values used are greater than 1 and there's no concern with using 0 as a base point for an axis.

In this case, the only thing you will be able to do is to download the chart as an image and manually edit it in a image editing software to get the axes to flip.

#### Feature Request:

You can however let Google know that this is a feature that is important for access to their APIs, and that you would like to request they implement it.

Google's Issue Tracker is a place for developers to report issues and make feature requests for their development services, I'd urge you to make a feature request there. The best component to file this under would be the [Sheets Editor component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=976&template=86308), as it would be a new Feature. Alternatively, you can suggest this by following the `Help > Report a problem` menu item from the Sheets UI.

There is a glimmer of hope for this! A feature request was made already for this, but ratrher than for Charts and Sheets, for use within Data Studio. This feature request you can see [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110373166),  to which you can click the star (☆) in the top left to let Google know more people want this kind of feature to be implemented.

#### References:

- [How to reverse the y-axis in a Google Sheets graph? - Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/119600)
- [Reverse only the left Y axis or Right Y Axis - Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110373166)
- [Sheets Editor Feature Request Form - Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=976&template=86308)